# Minecraft takes me to 'GameOutput' screen instead of launching

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos

So, I've been playing minecraft on my macbook pro for a while, but all of a sudden, the game has stopped launching. I mean, I can go to the launch screen, but when I click "play", it takes me to a new screen which is called game output. [image: WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE]

So, I was wondering if this happened to anyone else. I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but that didn't work. The funny thing is, it works on my cousin's laptop, but not mine.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of java do you have and have you tried reinstalling Java?

Comment: Have you updated Java lately? Perhaps to Java 8?

Comment: Please paste the contents of the "Launcher Log" tab when this happens.

Answer (score -1):

When reinstalling, have you tried to remove your **whole** `.minecraft` folder? If you don't know what `.minecraft` folder is, or where it is located at, then I recommend you remove it, it's located at `C:\Users\~YourUsername~\AppData\Roaming` and save your saves file on your desktop from the `.minecraft` folder, now try reinstalling minecraft using the `minecraft.msi` installer of the official minecraft.net site, [click me to get the installer](https://launcher.mojang.com/download/MinecraftInstaller.msi) no java is needed for this one, and will install itself automatically, once you've done that it should work fine, if not, please give me your log of `Launcher Log`, which includes the errors for us to help fix your problem.